# Resize image and upload

Tags: php

I want to write a php code for resizing images that are retrieved from database and upload it in the site. But i can't resize the images. That are directly uploaded into site without resize.. My code is given below ..thanks in advance ...

```
public function editimg()`enter code here`
     {
     $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
      $id=$this->input->post('hiddenimgid');     
      $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/movies';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
      $config['max_size']   = '150';
      $config['max_width']  = '199';
      $config['max_height']  = '199';
    //echo "hii";die;
    // print_r($config);die;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        { 
            //echo "not uploaded";die;
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$data['message'] = "Image Cannot be Uploaded,Try Again !!";
            $data['error']=$error;

        $this->index_one($data);

        } //if

        else
        {
            //echo "hii";die;
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $image_data         = $this->upload->data();
            $filename           = $image_data['file_name'];
            $source_path        = 'assets/img/movies/'.$filename ;
            $new_image_path     = 'assets/img/movies/'.$image_data['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$image_data['file_ext']; //name of resized image
            $target_path        = 'assets/img/movies/';
            $thumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $thumb['source_image']  = $source_path;
            $thumb['new_image']     = $target_path;
            $thumb['create_thumb']  = TRUE;
            $thumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $thumb['width']  = 140;
            $thumb['height'] = 200;
            //print_r($thumb);die;
            //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $thumb); 



                     if ( !$this->image_lib->resize())
                     { 
                        //echo "hii";die;
                        //$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $this->image_lib->display_errors('', '')); 
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $error= $this->image_lib->display_errors('', '')); 
                        print_r($error);die;
                     }
                    else
                    { 
                        //echo "hii";die;
                        //print_r($thumb);die;
                        $data=array(

                        'image'=>$new_image_path
                        );
                        //print_r($new_image_path);die;
                        if($this->movies_model->updateMovies($data,$id))         
                        {
                            $data['message'] = "Movies added successfully !!";
                            //$this->index_one($data);
                            redirect("movies/index", 'refresh');
                            //print_r($thumb);die;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $data['message'] = "not_uploaded !!";   
                        $this->index_one($data);
                        }
                    }
         }
}
```

`

Comment: you can use simple image resize code. You can get code from https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

Comment: sorry but ican't find any code for resize ...

Answer (score 0):

It simple to use Simple image

```
<?php

include('src/abeautifulsite/SimpleImage.php');

    try {
    $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('/*image name*/');
    $img->resize(320, 200)->save('/*name of resize image*/');resize image and save resized image

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oleh is correct, if you're struggling with image resizing it's best to use a library to handle all the edge cases and gotchas.

Here's how to do it with SimpleImage 2.x:

```
$image = new \abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('image.jpg');
$image->resize(320, 200)->save('result.jpg');
```

And SimpleImage 3.x:

```
$image = new \claviska\SimpleImage('image.jpg');
$image->resize(320, 200)->toFile('output.jpg');
```

The SimpleImage library can be installed with Composer:

```
composer require claviska/simpleimage
```

Or downloaded [from GitHub](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) and included manually.

Comment: Hi Cory, already DM you on twitter but i'll try here too!

The toFile() returns a SimpleImage object, how i can't transform that to a  regular $_FILE variable?  

What i need is just upload to my AWS S3 bucket after the manipulation, but the AWS Sdk use $_FILE as input

Comment: Don't try to simulate the behavior of $_FILE. The AWS SDK allows you to use putObject() with a number of options. If you're writing the output to a file, use putObject with a string as the `Body` parameter. e.g. $client->putObject([ 'Body' => file_get_contents('file.ext'), ...)

Comment: Thank you! @claviska Worked just fine! :)